# Format array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => controllers
    [1] => event
    [2] => add_new_file.php
)
```

I want to change it like

```
Array([controllers]=>[event]=>add_new_file.php)
```

Is there any idea about to change like this,Anyone have idea to change like this.

Comment: How did you get the Array like that in the first place? And what have you tried to do yourself?

Comment: @putvande I have path of different files,I explode that path ,and i get array like this

Comment: cam you give an example when there are more elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
$input  = array('controllers', 'event', 'add_new_file.php');
$output = null;

foreach (array_reverse($input) as $value) {
  if (is_null($output)) {
    $output = $value;
  } else {
    $output = array($value => $output);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  'controllers' => 
    array (size=1)
      'event' => string 'add_new_file.php' (length=16)
```

Answer (score 1):

While combination of `array_reverse()` and cycle will do the stuff, I was to late to post that (see good answer with that). So, this answer is just kind of joke (since I was curious - is it possible to resolve a matter with one-liner)

```
$rgData   = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
eval('$rgResult["'.join('"]["', array_slice($rgData, 0, -1)).'"] = "'.array_pop($rgData).'";');
//var_dump($rgResult);
```

(normally, never use `eval` - but it's academic interest, nothing more)

Comment: @hsz yep, I know. As I've said - only academic interest :p